# How many kilograms of each type of fertilizer should the farmer use?

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

> A farmer has a supply of chemical fertilizer of type A which contains 10% nitrogen and 5% phosphoric acid, and type B which contains 6% nitrogen and 10% phosphoric acid. After testing the soil conditions of the field, it was found that atleast 14 kg of nitrogen and 14 kg of phosphoric acid is required for producing a good crop. The fertilizer of type A costs Rs.5 per kg and the type B costs Rs.3 per kg. How many kg of each type of the fertilizer should be used to meet the requirement at the minimum possible cost? Using L.P.P. solve the above problem graphically.

Comment: Aside from typing the raw text of your homework, what effort have you made ? Unless you say where you are blocked, this question will be closed...

Comment: @JeanMarie hey there I have tried this and actually wanted to attach it with the question but as I am new here and lack experience with this platform I am not able to, it says I need 10 notices or something to be able to post them my equations are 10x+6y greater than or = 1400 and 5x+10y greater than or = 1400

Comment: @JeanMarie I am almost at the answer if there's any way I could post the picture so you guys could review it do let me know

Comment: Very well. Each one of these inequalities (to which you should add $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$) defines a half-plane : hatch each of them ; the quadrilateral region which is hatched four times is the "feasible region". Now take a moving line $ax+by=m$... that should be just touching the feasible region, as you have been taught, I assume in your lectures.

Comment: @JeanMarie I got Zmin min at two points (80,100) and (0, 700/3) the value of Zmin in both cases is 700 now how do we chose between them ? When both the points have same value

Comment: @user74981 See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865834/linear-programming-optimization-with-multiple-optimal-solutions/2866071#2866071) how a linear program can be solved graphically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequalities are right. Now see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865834/linear-programming-optimization-with-multiple-optimal-solutions/2866071#2866071) how to solve the a linear program graphically. Below the picture shows the graph of your problem.

> I got $Z_{min}$ min at two points (80,100) and (0, 700/3) the value of Zmin
>   in both cases is 700 now how do we chose between them ?

As you see at the graph that after the shift the objective function lies direcly on the first constraint $y\geq \frac{700}3-\frac53\cdot x$.  If we solve the objective function for y we get $y=\frac{z}3-\frac53\cdot x$

The reason why the objective function lies directly on the first constraint is that both have the same slope of $-\frac53$.

Thus the optimal solution is on every point on the constraint.

$(x^*,y^*)=\left(x, \frac{700}3-\frac53\cdot x\right)$, where $0\leq x\leq 80$

So both solutions you mentioned are valid. But all solutions in between them as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciated, I learnt something new today

Comment: @user74981 You are welcome. I´m glad that it helps.